# Finding $Cov(X_1^2, X_2^2)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, covariance

Assume $X_1, X_2$ are dependent random standard normal variables with $Cov(X_1,X_2)=a$.

> What is then the $Cov(X_1^2, X_2^2)$?

Are there known results for this without going technical into $\mathbb{E}{X^2_1 X_2^2}$ integration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is covered by [Isserlis's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem), which is about the expectation of products of standard normal random variables. We can write $\text{Cov}(X_1^2,X_2^2)$ as
$$
E[X_1^2X_2^2]-E[X_1^2]E[X_2^2]$$
using the definition of covariance. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are standard normal, then $E[X_1^2] = E[X_2^2] = 1$.

The implication of Isserlis' theorem for a 4th order product of normal variables $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ is
$$
E[Y_1 Y_2 Y_3 Y_4] = E[Y_1 Y_2]E[Y_3 Y_4] + E[Y_1 Y_3]E[Y_2 Y_4] + E[Y_1 Y_4]E[Y_2 Y_3]
$$
Replacing $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ each with $X_1$ and replacing $Y_3$ and $Y_4$ each with $X_2$, we get the following:
\begin{align}
E[X_1^2X_2^2] &= E[X_1^2]E[X_2^2] + E[X_1 X_2]E[X_1 X_2] + E[X_1 X_2]E[X_1 X_2] \\&= 1 + 2\text{Cov}(X_1, X_2)^2
\end{align}
So, $\text{Cov}(X_1^2,X_2^2) = 2\ \text{Cov}(X_1, X_2)^2$